# Error with local variable referenced before assignment, despite globalising it

Tags: python, tkinter

In my code, the user answers questions and a variable "score" is incremented each time. I have made score = 0 and then globalised it, yet whenever the user selects the correct answer and score needs to be incremented, the program says that score has been referenced before assignement.

```
global score 
score = str()
def correctscreen1():
    Label(text = 'Correct answer!', font = ("Calibri",12), fg = "GREEN").place(relx=0.017, rely=0.8, height=41, width=144)
    score = score + 1

def firstscreen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry("600x450")
    screen.title("Finite State Machines")
    Label(text = 'Finite State Machines', font = ("Calibri",14)).place(relx=0.267, rely=0.022, height=71, width=254)
    Label(text = 'What is a Finite State Machine', font = ("Calibri",10)).place(relx=0.017, rely=0.178, height=41, width=194)
    Button(text = 'Models used to design programs & logic circuits', command = correctscreen1).place(relx=0.033, rely=0.267, height=44, width=265)
    Button(text = 'Models used to design programs & logic circuits',command = incorrectscreen1).place(relx=0.033, rely=0.4, height=44, width=265)
    Button(text = 'Models used to design programs & logic circuits',command = incorrectscreen1).place(relx=0.033, rely=0.533, height=44, width=265)
    Button(text = 'Models used to design programs & logic circuits',command = incorrectscreen1).place(relx=0.033, rely=0.667, height=44, width=265)

line 15, in correctscreen1
    score = score + 1 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'score' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: the global keyword needs to be inside the function correctscreen1

Comment: You probably want to initialize `score = 0` instead; you can't add the `int` value 1 to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`global` is used *inside* a function, to indicate that a name that would otherwise have local scope should refer to a global name instead. Using `global` in the global scope is harmless, but meaningless.

```
def firstscreen():
    global screen, score
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign `score` a value before referencing it, try :

```
score = 0
def correctscreen1():
        Label(text = 'Correct answer!', font = ("Calibri",12), fg = "GREEN").place(relx=0.017, rely=0.8, height=41, width=144)
        score = score + 1`
```